# How to download data from the Reptile database using r

Tags: r, web-scraping, tidyverse, httr

I am using R to try and download images from the Reptile-database by filling their form to seek for specific images. For that, I am following previous suggestions to fill a form online from R, such as:

```
library(httr)
library(tidyverse)

POST(
url = "http://reptile-database.reptarium.cz/advanced_search",
encode = "json",
body = list(
genus = "Chamaeleo",
species = "dilepis"
)) -> res

out <- content(res)[1]
```

This seems to work smoothly, but my problem now is to identify the link with the correct species name in the resulting out object.

This object should contain the following page:
https://reptile-database.reptarium.cz/species?genus=Chamaeleo&species=dilepis&search_param=%28%28genus%3D%27Chamaeleo%27%29%28species%3D%27dilepis%27%29%29

This contains names with links. Thus, i would like to identify the link that takes me to the page with the correct species's table. however I am unable to find the link nor even the name of the species within the generated out object.

Comment: I don't get your code to work though? It does not get past the search page

Comment: Thanks Tom, but do you get any output in out? Maybe what I get in out is not the actual page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I only extract the links to the pictures. Simply `map` or `apply` a function to download them with `download.file()`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

genus <- "Chamaeleo"
species <- "dilepis"

pics <- paste0(
  "http://reptile-database.reptarium.cz/species?genus=", genus,
  "&species=", species) %>%
  read_html() %>% 
  html_elements("#gallery img") %>%
  html_attr("src")

 [1] "https://www.reptarium.cz/content/photo_rd_05/Chamaeleo-dilepis-03000034021_01_t.jpg"
 [2] "https://www.reptarium.cz/content/photo_rd_05/Chamaeleo-dilepis-03000033342_01_t.jpg"
 [3] "https://www.reptarium.cz/content/photo_rd_02/Chamaeleo-dilepis-03000029987_01_t.jpg"
 [4] "https://www.reptarium.cz/content/photo_rd_02/Chamaeleo-dilepis-03000029988_01_t.jpg"
 [5] "https://www.reptarium.cz/content/photo_rd_05/Chamaeleo-dilepis-03000035130_01_t.jpg"
 [6] "https://www.reptarium.cz/content/photo_rd_05/Chamaeleo-dilepis-03000035131_01_t.jpg"
 [7] "https://www.reptarium.cz/content/photo_rd_05/Chamaeleo-dilepis-03000035132_01_t.jpg"
 [8] "https://www.reptarium.cz/content/photo_rd_05/Chamaeleo-dilepis-03000035133_01_t.jpg"
 [9] "https://www.reptarium.cz/content/photo_rd_06/Chamaeleo-dilepis-03000036237_01_t.jpg"
[10] "https://www.reptarium.cz/content/photo_rd_06/Chamaeleo-dilepis-03000036238_01_t.jpg"
[11] "https://www.reptarium.cz/content/photo_rd_06/Chamaeleo-dilepis-03000036239_01_t.jpg"
[12] "https://www.reptarium.cz/content/photo_rd_11/Chamaeleo-dilepis-03000041048_01_t.jpg"
[13] "https://www.reptarium.cz/content/photo_rd_11/Chamaeleo-dilepis-03000041049_01_t.jpg"
[14] "https://www.reptarium.cz/content/photo_rd_11/Chamaeleo-dilepis-03000041050_01_t.jpg"
[15] "https://www.reptarium.cz/content/photo_rd_11/Chamaeleo-dilepis-03000041051_01_t.jpg"
[16] "https://www.reptarium.cz/content/photo_rd_12/Chamaeleo-dilepis-03000042287_01_t.jpg"
[17] "https://www.reptarium.cz/content/photo_rd_12/Chamaeleo-dilepis-03000042288_01_t.jpg"
[18] "https://calphotos.berkeley.edu/imgs/128x192/9121_3261/2921/0070.jpeg"               
[19] "https://calphotos.berkeley.edu/imgs/128x192/1338_3161/0662/0074.jpeg"               
[20] "https://calphotos.berkeley.edu/imgs/128x192/9121_3261/2921/0082.jpeg"               
[21] "https://calphotos.berkeley.edu/imgs/128x192/1338_3152/3386/0125.jpeg"               
[22] "https://calphotos.berkeley.edu/imgs/128x192/6666_6666/1009/0136.jpeg"               
[23] "https://calphotos.berkeley.edu/imgs/128x192/6666_6666/0210/0057.jpeg"
```